# Migration to CakePHP 4.4 undefined method in Entity problem

Tags: cakephp

I am migrating from CakePHP 3.10 to CakePHP 4.4. My code worked fine in the previous version of the framework. At this moment I am getting error:
"Call to undefined method App\Model\Entity\A1::getMyValue()"
while calling in the controller: $test->getMyValue(). $test is correct App\Model\Entity\A1 Object. What is incorrect? The following is my entity class:

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class A1 extends Entity{
   protected $_accessible = ['*' => true,];
     
   protected function _getMyValue(){
      return 'AAA';
   }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `getMyValue`, but the function name is actually `_getMyValue`? And it's a protected function? I doubt that ever worked. What I think you're looking for is to use `$test->myValue` and Cake will call this function through its accessor automagic.

Comment: It actually does work correctly on my second computer with CakePHP 3.10 and PHP 7

Comment: The protected funtion is also suggested at the documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-fields (in "Creating Virtual Fields" section) so it should work also in version 4

Comment: Yes, it should be a virtual function. But you should not be calling it directly, as described in the very same bit of the documentation that you've referenced. Directly accessing a protected function from outside the class in question is something that PHP simply does not allow, hence why I'm pretty sure that what you're saying worked in 3.10 is not implemented exactly like you're saying it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use public methods (and not "magic" virtual fields) if it is sufficient for your use case because then it is just simple PHP without any magic from CakePHP.

```
public function getMyValue() {
    return 'AAA';
}
```

if you need to use virtual fields than access it this way:
`_getMyValue()` -> access by call `->my_value`
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a trap in the cookbook. Same page but different topic. If you want to access the virtual field, you have to expose it with $_virtual in the entity-class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class A1 extends Entity{
   protected $_accessible = ['*' => true,];
   protected $_virtual = ['my_value'];
     
   protected function _getMyValue(){
      return 'AAA';
   }
}
```

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-fields